# JMS: activemq-version.properties is not available

Tags: java, jms, activemq-classic, wildfly, wildfly-10

I am trying to establish a JMS connection. In connectionFactory.createContext, I get an error that the ActiveMQ version loader reports that a properties file is missing:

> Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: activemq-version.properties is not available
>     at org.apache.activemq.artemis.utils.VersionLoader.getVersion(VersionLoader.java:87)

I am running the project from Eclipse - so it's most likely an eclipse classpath issue, but I can't find which library is missing.

Full stacktrace:

```
javax.jms.JMSRuntimeException: Failed to create session factory
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.client.JmsExceptionUtils.convertToRuntimeException(JmsExceptionUtils.java:88)
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.client.ActiveMQConnectionFactory.createContext(ActiveMQConnectionFactory.java:262)
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.client.ActiveMQConnectionFactory.createContex    t(ActiveMQConnectionFactory.java:248)
    at at.cone.health.dispo.online.DispoServerFacadeImpl$JMSReceiverThread.run(DispoServerFacadeImpl.java:109)
Caused by: javax.jms.JMSException: Failed to create session factory
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.client.ActiveMQConnectionFactory.createConnectionInternal(ActiveMQConnectionFactory.java:727)
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.client.ActiveMQConnectionFactory.createContext(ActiveMQConnectionFactory.java:255)
    ... 2 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: activemq-version.properties is not available
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.utils.VersionLoader.getVersion(VersionLoader.java:87)
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.protocol.core.impl.ActiveMQClientProtocolManager.<init>(ActiveMQClientProtocolManager.java:81)
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.protocol.core.impl.ActiveMQClientProtocolManagerFactory.newProtocolManager(ActiveMQClientProtocolManagerFactory.java:49)
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ServerLocatorImpl.newProtocolManager(ServerLocatorImpl.java:575)
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ClientSessionFactoryImpl.<init>(ClientSessionFactoryImpl.java:173)
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ServerLocatorImpl.createSessionFactory(ServerLocatorImpl.java:757)
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.client.ActiveMQConnectionFactory.createConnectionInternal(ActiveMQConnectionFactory.java:724)
... 3 more
```

The code where I try to set up the connection:
                    InitialContext namingContext = new InitialContext(env);

```
                ConnectionFactory connectionFactory = (ConnectionFactory) namingContext.lookup(CONNECTION_FACTORY);
                System.out.println("Got ConnectionFactory " + CONNECTION_FACTORY);

                destination = (Destination) namingContext.lookup(DESTINATION);

                System.out.println("Got JMS Endpoint " + DESTINATION);

                final JMSContext context = connectionFactory.createContext("internal", "internal");

                this.context = context;

                JMSConsumer consumer = context.createConsumer(destination, "client='" + clientUID + "'", true);

                // Then receive the same number of messages that were sent
```

The project is ANT based, so I cannot use maven dependency management. Nevertheless, the server part uses a maven build, so I have a local maven repository and an eclipse build path variable M2_REPO pointing to the .m2 directory. I tried to set up a library dependency in my eclipse project. I am running the project from eclipse, so we can - at first - ignore ANT related dependencies, and focus just on eclipse (but without maven).

I added a library dependency to the wildfly-client-all-10.0.0.Final.jar from my maven repo (using my M2_REPO variable, extended by the path). The library is correctly displayed as referenced library in the eclipse project.

I implemented a demo with same lines of codes in an eclipse maven project. Here I didn't get an exception, in the demo I was able to receive messages. So I assume it's a classpath issue.

I also searched for the missing activemq-version.properties on google and on stackoverflow, but didn't find anything related. I also didn't find a resource called activemq-version.properties, even not in the demo project (and its dependencied) where it was executed successfully.

Answer (score 0):

After some more investigation, I did now identify the reason.

In the run config, I had a different classpath. This classpath remained from an elder configuration. Here, I didn't use the same jar as the maven build. The run configuration contained both the jboss-client.jar and the jboss-cli-client.jar from wildfly/bin/client directory.

This configuration was wrong, and caused an additional warning which I didn't recognize in my logs, but which was also a hint to the solution:

> WARN: EJB client integration will not be available due to a problem setting up the EJB client handler

I changed it to the wildfly-client-all-10.0.0.Final.jar which is also contained in maven project runtimes, but it again didn't solve the issue.

Then I found this article: https://developer.jboss.org/thread/267824

Solution: back to the first configuration approach for the runtime config, using the JAR from wildfly\bin\client directory, but only the jboss-cli-client.jar AND NOT the jboss-client-jar.